# Por que a sessão do PHP não funciona se já tenho uma variável na super global $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

Tenho o seguinte código no arquivo **config.php**:

```
<?php
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE )
{
    session_start();
}

$_SESSION['id_sessao'] = session_id();

...
```

Acontece que quando envio o formulário de login para inserir mais um dado na sessão que nesse caso seria `$_SESSION['login']` , isso não ocorre.

A página do login está assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
...
$login = $_REQUEST['login'];
$_SESSION['login'] = $login;

...
```

Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: Como verificou que "não funciona"? Você garantiu que o valor do formulário chegasse corretamente ao PHP?

Comment: Sim. Usei var_dump($_SESSION); e lá encontrei o valor de session_id();

Comment: Apenas minha variável não entra lá. Testei no localhost e está ok, mas quando tento online não funciona.

Comment: O formulário é submetido via ajax jQuery e tenho resposta da página de login.php no formato .json.